# How do you get the first 36 characters of a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string, and I don't know if it is more than 36 characters or not. If it is longer that 36 characters I only want the first 36 characters:

```
var longString = "sdfkjhs3 234kjh khjk 234kjh 234kj h23k423h4 23k4";
var templongString = longString.substring... ?
```

Edit

I was trying

```
var longString = "sdfkjhs3 234kjh khjk 234kjh 234kj h23k423h4 23k4";
var templongString = templongString.substring(longstring, 36);
```

Comment: Please do not rollback my edits. Your question has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Because simply looking up the [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method could have answered your question.

Comment: @Paulpro  i was trying to delete question and by mistake rolled back your changes, sorry...

Comment: Consult the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: Negative vote because you didn't specify [what you already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).

Answer (score 5):

```
var templongString = longString.substring(0, 36);
```

This will truncate the string to 36 characters.

Comment: @AlienArrays what about the spaces? It's just a string

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if(longString.length > 36) {
     var templongString = longString.substring(0, 36);
}
```

Comment: The `if` is redundant. If the string length is less than 36,  `substring(0, 36)` [will return the entire string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#Description).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String.prototype.slice` method (which also saves a few characters):

```
var newString = longString.slice(0, 36);
```

I personally prefer this implementation as it's expected behaviour aligns with `Array.prototype.slice`.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? The link you provided actually contradicts what you're saying except for the one case in Chrome 33 generally substr is faster (with long strings)